# Function that counts the number of occurences of a substring within a longer string

Tags: python, substring, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Find a function that takes 3 arguments: base string, substring to search for in the base string, and a boolean argument to tell if it is case-insensitive (default, true) or case-sensitive (false). Return how many times the substring was found. No additional imports besides upper() and lower(), so far I have:

```
def count_substring(base, sub, case_default=True):

length = len(sub)
times = 0

if case_default == False:
    for i in range(len(base)-len(sub)+1):
        if (base[i:i+len(sub)] == sub):
            times +=1
else:
    base.lower()
    sub.lower()
    for i in range(len(base)-len(sub)+1):
        if (base[i:i+len(sub)] == sub):
            times +=1

return times
```

This works for the case sensitive but not case insensitive.

Comment: you should use `base = base.lower()` and `sub = sub.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it; just note that `.lower()` returns a new string rather than modifying the string in-place!

```
def count_substring(base, sub, case_insensitive=True):
    times = 0
    if case_insensitive:
        base = base.lower()
        sub = sub.lower()

    for i in range(len(base)-len(sub)+1):
        if (base[i:i+len(sub)] == sub):
            times += 1

    return times
```

An easier solution might be to use `split`, which is part of `str` and therefore does not require an import:

```
def count_substring(base, sub, case_insensitive=True):
    if case_insensitive:
        base = base.lower()
        sub = sub.lower()
    return len(base.split(sub)) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
base.lower()  
sub.lower()
```

Update this two line like this.

```
base = base.lower()
sub = sub.lower()
```